# Divide and Conquer - Get count of Zero Sum Slices

Tags: python-3.x

I have a question regarding a piece of code I'm writing. This is to get the number of slices in an array that add up to zero. However, I would like to be able to do this in Python using recursion. Please take a look at my code and let me know if you see something off. I am not getting correct answers when comparing to the iterative approach.

```
def sumzeros(A, low, mid, high):
    leftsum = 0
    rightsum = 0
    counter = 0

    for i in range(low, mid+1):
        leftsum += A[i]

    for j in range(mid+1, high+1):
        rightsum += A[j]

    if leftsum + rightsum == 0:
        counter += 1

    return counter


def solution(A, low, high):
    if low == high:
        if A[low] == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    else:
        mid = (low + high) // 2

        left = solution(A, low, mid)
        right = solution(A, mid+1, high)
        cross = sumzeros(A, low, mid, high)

        return cross + left + right

print('Recursive solution: Number of sum zeros = {}'.format(solution(A, 0, len(A) - 1)))
```

Answer (score 0):

use **mid = (low + high) / 2** or **mid = high - (high - low) / 2**

Comment: Neither of those gave the correct answer. The second option actually caused a max recursion issue. 

I used the following example [0,0,0] and [2, -2, 3, 0, 4, -7] and both gave the wrong answer. The correct answer for [0,0,0] is 6 and the correct answer for [2, -2, 3, 0, 4, -7] is 4.